# Cypress installtion halts in between

Tags: cypress

I am trying to install cypress on windows 10 with node v12.16.1 and npm 6.13.4.
Cypress getting installed is having version 9.4.1. it hangs as shown in image. nothing happens after this point

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIFug.png)

[installation window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIFug.png)

Comment: How long have you waited? It's downloading a lot of data, it might take a while.

Comment: i am waiting since long, 30 minutes almost

Comment: You should cancel and retry installing or maybe update your node and npm version.

Comment: it's because cypress app while installing needs internet connection, corporate proxy was blocking. version 9.0 printed clear message about this but 9.4.1 which is the latest one not printing anything on console, so got confused

Answer (score 0):

It's because cypress app while installing needs internet connection, corporate proxy was blocking. version 9.0 printed clear message about this but 9.4.1 which is the latest one not printing anything on console

Comment: I have this exact issue. How did you end up solving the corporate proxy issue? I've tried setting the HTTP_PROXY environment var that all the other answers say but it doesn't help with the 'npx cypress install' command